# Load a variable from dotenv file when starting PM2

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I am starting instances of my app as a `package.json` script with PM2 this way:

```
"start:pm2": "pm2 start -i max node myapp.js"
```

I found out that not all members in the team always want to use `max` as a value for instances number while developing, but prefer to use some lower value.

To not change `package.json` I would better let them change the value inside `.env` file because we already use it so that the value from it would be used as the parameter to pm2.

I know I can create a wrapper js or bash script to load the variable from `.env` file and pass it to pm2 but it would be better to have a solution without it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better pattern here is to remove dotenv from your code and "require" it on the command line.  This makes your code nicely transportable between any environment (including cloud-based) - which is one of the main features of environment variables.

a) code up your .env file alongside your script (e.g. app.js)

b) to run your script without pm2:

```
node -r dotenv/config app.js
```

c) in pm2.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name      : 'My Application',
    script    : 'app.js',
    node_args : '-r dotenv/config',
    ...
  }],
}
```

and then
`pm2 start pm2.config.js`

*Note: the use of dotenv/config on the command line is one of the best practices recommended by dotenv themselves*

Comment: You might need to specify a custom path to your `.env` file, in which case you can use the PM2 config property 'args' in addition to the above, like so:

`args: 'dotenv_config_path=relative/path/to/.env'`

Comment: Adding to the great tip by @TJBlackman, remember that the path is relative to `cwd` if you specified it.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an [`ecosystem.config.js`](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/ecosystem-file/) file and [declare your environment variables](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/best-practices/environment-variables/#set-environment-1) under the “env:” attribute, in your case the [`NODE_APP_INSTANCE`](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/load-balancing/#cluster-environment-variable) can be used to set the number of instances:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "MyApp",
    script: "./myapp.js",
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: "development",
      NODE_APP_INSTANCE: "max"
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: "production",
    }
  }]
}
```

Then call `pm2 start` or `pm2 start /path/to/ecosystem.config.js` to load an ecosystem from an other folder.

Comment: upvoted! and done but how do you access NODE_APP_INSTANCE in some file if you want to, lets say for running tests

Comment: @PirateApp `process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE`, check http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/#specific-environment-variables